# Foreign Key Constraint Set Back to Trusted

Tags: sql-server, index, foreign-key, constraint

We have some production tables with numerous constraints that are not trusted at the moment.  We're having them checked/trusted so they can be used again.  We know that the optimizer has not been using them in its plans (because they weren't trusted).  I have two questions before setting them back to trusted.

1. Will the optimizer recognize the change and consider them before using cached query plans for re-run transactions? Put another way, do I need to consider removing any query plans?
2. Is it safe to say this is a situation where SQL Server has been rebuilding the index (we do have this turned on), and maintaining the index throughout inserts, updates, and deletes, but simply not using the foreign key?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Will the optimizer recognize the change and consider them before using cached query plans for re-run transactions? Put another way, do I need to consider removing any query plans?

Yes, the optimizer should recompile the plans since changes to an underlying table are one of the triggers that result in a plan recompilation. Since checking a constraint involves an `ALTER TABLE` command,

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[table] CHECK CONSTRAINT [fk_table]
```

this should qualify it as a valid reason to update the plans, according to this [TechNet article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181055(v=sql.105).aspx) (from 2008 R2 but should stand true for current versions as well) which specifies that a `ALTER TABLE` or `ALTER VIEW` command will qualify.

> Is it safe to say this is a situation where SQL Server has been
>   rebuilding the index (we do have this turned on), and maintaining the
>   index throughout inserts, updates, and deletes, but simply not using
>   the foreign key?

Correct. As you've observed the optimizer ignores the foreign key when creating query plans - no operation involving the table will make use of the foreign key while it is untrusted, whether that is a rebuild or an insert, update, etc.